# How do you express binary literals in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, binary, integer, literals

How do you express an integer as a binary number with Python literals?

I was easily able to find the answer for hex:

```
>>> 0x12AF
4783
>>> 0x100
256
```

and octal:

```
>>> 01267
695
>>> 0100
64
```

**How do you use literals to express binary in Python?**

---

***Summary of Answers***

- Python 2.5 and earlier: can express binary using `int('01010101111',2)` but not with a literal.
- Python 2.5 and earlier: there is *no way* to express binary literals.
- Python 2.6 beta: You can do like so: `0b1100111` or `0B1100111`.
- Python 2.6 beta: will also allow `0o27` or `0O27` (second character is the letter O) to represent an octal.
- Python 3.0 beta: Same as 2.6, but will no longer allow the older `027` syntax for octals.

Answer (score 358, accepted):

For reference—*future* Python possibilities:
Starting with Python 2.6 you can express binary literals using the prefix **0b** or **0B**:

```
>>> 0b101111
47
```

You can also use the new **bin** function to get the binary representation of a number:

```
>>> bin(173)
'0b10101101'
```

Development version of the documentation: [What's New in Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3127-integer-literal-support-and-syntax)

Answer (score 85):

```
>>> print int('01010101111',2)
687
>>> print int('11111111',2)
255
```

Another way.

Comment: This is interesting for when you have strings, but if working with pure numbers, you add unnecessary computations to the code.

Answer (score 41):

> ## How do you express binary literals in Python?

They're not "binary" literals, but rather, "integer literals". You can express integer literals with a binary format with a `0` followed by a `B` or `b` followed by a series of zeros and ones, for example:

```
>>> 0b0010101010
170
>>> 0B010101
21
```

From the Python 3 [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals), these are the ways of providing integer literals in Python:

> Integer literals are described by the following lexical definitions:
>
> ```
> integer      ::=  decinteger | bininteger | octinteger | hexinteger
> decinteger   ::=  nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)* | "0"+ (["_"] "0")*
> bininteger   ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") (["_"] bindigit)+
> octinteger   ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") (["_"] octdigit)+
> hexinteger   ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") (["_"] hexdigit)+
> nonzerodigit ::=  "1"..."9"
> digit        ::=  "0"..."9"
> bindigit     ::=  "0" | "1"
> octdigit     ::=  "0"..."7"
> hexdigit     ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"
> ```
>
> There is no limit for the length of integer literals apart from what
>   can be stored in available memory.
>
> Note that leading zeros in a non-zero decimal number are not allowed.
>   This is for disambiguation with C-style octal literals, which Python
>   used before version 3.0.
>
> Some examples of integer literals:
>
> ```
> 7     2147483647                        0o177    0b100110111
> 3     79228162514264337593543950336     0o377    0xdeadbeef
>       100_000_000_000                   0b_1110_0101
> ```
>
> *Changed in version 3.6:* Underscores are now allowed for grouping purposes in literals.

### Other ways of expressing binary:

You can have the zeros and ones in a string object which can be manipulated (although you should probably just do bitwise operations on the integer in most cases) - just pass int the string of zeros and ones and the base you are converting from (2):

```
>>> int('010101', 2)
21
```

You can optionally have the `0b` or `0B` prefix:

```
>>> int('0b0010101010', 2)
170
```

If you pass it `0` as the base, it will assume base 10 if the string doesn't specify with a prefix:

```
>>> int('10101', 0)
10101
>>> int('0b10101', 0)
21
```

### Converting from int back to human readable binary:

You can pass an integer to bin to see the string representation of a binary literal:

```
>>> bin(21)
'0b10101'
```

And you can combine `bin` and `int` to go back and forth:

```
>>> bin(int('010101', 2))
'0b10101'
```

You can use a format specification as well, if you want to have minimum width with preceding zeros:

```
>>> format(int('010101', 2), '{fill}{width}b'.format(width=10, fill=0))
'0000010101'
>>> format(int('010101', 2), '010b')
'0000010101'
```

Comment: `int(hex(1234), 16) = 1234`   :D

Answer (score 3):

0 in the start here specifies that the base is 8 (not 10), which is pretty easy to see:

```
>>> int('010101', 0)
4161
```

If you don't start with a 0, then python assumes the number is base 10.

```
>>> int('10101', 0)
10101
```

Answer (score 3):

**I've tried this in Python 3.6.9**

**Convert Binary to Decimal**

```
>>> 0b101111
47

>>> int('101111',2)
47
```

**Convert Decimal to binary**

```
>>> bin(47)
'0b101111'
```

**Place a 0 as the second parameter python assumes it as decimal.**

```
>>> int('101111',0)
101111
```

Answer (score 1):

Another good method to get an integer representation from binary is to use eval()

Like so:

```
def getInt(binNum = 0):
    return eval(eval('0b' + str(n)))
```

I guess this is a way to do it too.
I hope this is a satisfactory answer :D

Comment: Nope, not a good method at all. You should **never** use `eval()`.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell Python, up through 2.5, only supports hexadecimal & octal literals.  I did find some discussions about adding binary to future versions but nothing definite.

Answer (score -3):

I am pretty sure this is one of the things due to change in Python 3.0 with perhaps bin() to go with hex() and oct().

EDIT:
lbrandy's answer is correct in all cases.