# How can I make `bin(30)` return `00011110` instead of `0b11110`?

Tags: python

What does the `b` stand for in the output of `bin(30)`: `0b11110`? Is there any way I can get rid of this `b`? How can I get the output of `bin()` to always return a standard 8 digit output?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Using [zfill()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

> Return the numeric string left filled with zeros in a string of length width. A sign prefix is handled correctly. The original string is returned if width is less than len(s).

```
>>> bin(30)[2:].zfill(8)
'00011110'
>>>
```

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: Surprisingly this appears to be the fastest, but ackkkk.

Comment: @loannis Your edit caused problems because now the wrong result was provided for negative values, -30 != 30 whereas your edit results in `bin(30).lstrip('-0b').zfill(8) == bin(-30).lstrip('-0b').zfill(8)`

Answer (score 34):

0b is like 0x - it indicates the number is formatted in binary (0x indicates the number is in hex).

See [How do you express binary literals in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476/how-do-you-express-binary-literals-in-python)

See http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3127-integer-literal-support-and-syntax

To strip off the 0b it's easiest to use string slicing: `bin(30)[2:]`

And similarly for format to 8 characters wide:

```
('00000000'+bin(30)[2:])[-8:]
```

Alternatively you can use the [string formatter](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) (in 2.6+) to do it all in one step:

```
"{0:08b}".format(30)
```

Comment: +1 for `string.format` answer, beat me to it

Comment: For this case I prefer the format built in function instead of the format method: format(30, '08b') as opposed to "{0:08b}".format(30)

Comment: Don’t use `str.format()` for a single placeholder and nothing else. That’s what we have `format()` for: `format(30, '08b')`

Answer (score 20):

Take advantage of the famous **`format()`** function with the lesser known second argument and chain it with **`zfill()`**

**`'b'` - Binary
`'x'` - Hex
`'o'` - Octal
`'d'` - Decimal**

```
>>> print format(30, 'b')
11110
>>> print format(30, 'b').zfill(8)
00011110
```

Should do. Here `'b'` stands for binary just like `'x'`, `'o'` & `'d'` for hexadecimal, octal and decimal respectively.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *format* in *Python 2* or *Python 3*:

```
>> print( format(15, '08b') )
00001111
```

[]'s

Answer (score 3):

You can use this too :

```
 bi=bin(n)[2:]
```

This will remove the `'0b'` portion of the returned value and you can use the output anywhere .

Answer (score 1):

The current answers don't consider negative values (thanks @Gui13 for the comment!) in which case you get `-0b...` instead of just `0b...`. You can handle both with a simple `if-else` where the value is checked whether it's less than zero or not

```
>>> def printBit(x):
    if x < 0:
        return '-' + bin(x)[3:].zfill(8) # replace 
    else:
        return bin(x)[2:].zfill(8)

>>> print(printBit(30))
'00011110'
>>> print(printBit(-30))
'-00011110'
```

or by using `replace()`

```
>>> print(bin(30)).replace('0b', '').zfill(8)
```

The problem with the call above is that one of the bits gets "lost" to the `-` sign due to the same value being used for the `zfill()`. You can handle this too  with a simple ternary check:

```
>>> x = 30
>>> print(bin(x)).replace('0b', '').zfill(9 if x < 0 else 8)
'00011110'

>>> x = -30
>>> print(bin(x)).replace('0b', '').zfill(9 if x < 0 else 8)
'-00011110'
```

Last but not least you can also make the `zfill()` to automatically adapt the number of `0`s to match a byte (8 bits) or a `n` number of bit quadruplets (4 bits):

```
>>> def pb(x):
    bres = bin(x).replace('0b', '').replace('-', '') # If no minus, second replace doesn't do anything
    lres = len(bres) # We need the length to see how many 0s we need to add to get a quadruplets
    # We adapt the number of added 0s to get full bit quadruplets.
    # The '-' doesn't count since we want to handle it separately from the bit string
    bres = bres = ('-' if x < 0 else '') + bres.zfill(lres + (4-lres%4))

    return bres

>>> print(pb(7))
'0111'
>>> print(pb(-7))
'-0111'
>>> print(pb(30))
'00011110'
>>> print(pb(-30))
'-00011110'
```

Here is the final version with adaptable filling of `0`s and additional split with space every `n` characters (where the `n` is determined by filling factor):

```
>>> def pb(x, fillingBits=4, splitWithSpace=True):
    # If no minus, second replace doesn't do anything
    bres = bin(x).replace('0b', '').replace('-', '')
    lres = len(bres)

    bres = bres.zfill(lres + (fillingBits - (lres % fillingBits)))
    lres = len(bres)

    # We can also add a blank after every fillingBits character
    if splitWithSpace:
        bres = ' '.join([bres[i:(i + fillingBits)] for i in range(0, lres, fillingBits)])

    bres = ('-' if x < 0 else '') + bres
    # We remove any trailing/leading blanks (occurring whenever splitWithSpace enabled)
    return bres.strip()

>>> print(pb(7))
'0111'
>>> print(pb(-7))
'-0111'
>>> print(pb(30))
'0001 1110'
>>> print(pb(-30))
'-0001 1110'
```

Comment: Read before acting "smart". The OP clearly asks about padding plus the fact that `bin()` (at least at the time I wrote this answer) does NOT handle two complement and a negative number is returned as `-` followed by the converted  binary. The accepted answer even removes the `-`, which makes results in a negative being the same as a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

**python 2.7**

print "{0:b}".format(30)

**python 3.x**

print ('{0:b}'.format(30))

Comment: Both of the snippets will work on python 2.x and both will result in a syntax error on python 3.x, since print is a function in 3.x. Did you perhaps mean to  make the second snippet `print("{0:b}".format(30))`?

Comment: you're right , i have forget that print in python 3.x is with (), i will it new edit