# brute forcer algorithm with all possible combinations / permutation in a given char array

Tags: java, algorithm

Need help for this simple thing that is annoying me.
I have seen many similar algorithms but I want to do this in **exactly** the stated way to reach **ALL** possible combinations / permutation in a given charset array.

lets take an example of a password cracker brute forcer

e.g  `char[] charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();` ?

**stated way:**

its like this.   for the current example.

```
a,b,c,d......z     then at last index "z".  

it goes like      

aa,ab,ac....az.        then      

ba,bb,bc,bd........bz          then

same for ca, cb, and so on.

aaaa,aaab,aaac......aaaz   then

baaa,baab,baac.......baaz   to      zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

**Code I reached so far:**

(well not a solution though) is to have as many for loops as the length of charset array. that is insane.  this works ok. but i need intelligent one.

```
public class Bruteforcer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          char[] charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();


         int currentIndex = 0;
         String currentString = "";

         for (int i = 0; i < charset.length; i++) {
            char currentChar = charset[i];

             for (int j = 0; j < charset.length; j++) {

                 char c = charset[j];
                 currentString =  "" +currentChar + c;
                 System.out.println(currentString);

             }


         }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can use two loops to explore all the combinations.

Comment: Solution for this problem can be easily googled.

Comment: ya, but I didnt got one. and I do want to learn with specific example. there are many different ones on google though

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/better-way-to-generate-all-combinations

Comment: thats javascript and not the way I stated that i wanted

Comment: You stated that you wanted an algorithm... now you have it. SO is not a code generator.

Comment: thanks for the help :) but i was looking guide on my "stated way"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074991/generate-all-permutations-of-all-lengths

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361/generate-list-of-all-possible-permutations-of-a-string

Comment: Agree with @d'alar'cop that the algorithm is actually already available virtually everywhere, and some other answers are actually simpler =D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this without recursion, it helps to keep an array of the indices for your current result.  Here is a template class that will produce the result you are looking for:

```
public abstract class Bruteforce
{
  public void generate( char[] input ) {
    char[] result = new char[input.length];
    int[] index = new int[input.length];

    // initialize the arrays.
    Arrays.fill(result, 0, result.length, input[0]);
    Arrays.fill(index,  0, index.length, 0);

    // loop over the output lengths.
    for( int length = 1; length <= input.length; length++ ) {
      int updateIndex = 0;
      do {
        element(result, 0, length);

        // update values that need to reset.
        for(updateIndex = length-1;
            updateIndex != -1 && ++index[updateIndex] == input.length;
            result[updateIndex] = input[0], index[updateIndex] = 0, updateIndex--);

        // update the character that is not resetting, if valid
        if( updateIndex != -1 ) result[updateIndex] = input[index[updateIndex]];
      }
      while(updateIndex != -1);
    }
  }
  public void generate( String input ) {
    generate(input.toCharArray());
  }
  public abstract void element(char[] result, int offset, int length);
}
```

You can then extend the template to print each element to STDOUT:

```
new Bruteforce() {
  public void element(char[] result, int offset, int length) {
    System.out.println(new String(result, offset, length));
  }
}.generate("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

NOTE: This code assumes that the input string does not contain any duplicate characters.

Comment: Great!! spare me some minutes to observe

Comment: PERFECT so far!! are you sure that it would not miss ANY combination / permutation that could be made by any chars of given array?

Comment: If the input string does not contain duplicate characters, then this code will produce all of the elements you are looking for, in the specified order.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use recursion. The complexity of the algorithm is exponential. I hope I understood the problem.

```
public class Generator {
    private char[] charset;

    public Generator()
    {
        charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    }


    public void generate(String str, int pos, int length)
    {
        if (length == 0) {
            System.out.println(str);
        } else {
            for (int i = pos; i < charset.length; i++) {
                generate(str + charset[i], i, length - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Generator test = new Generator();
        //test.generate("", 1);
        for (int length = 1;  length < 5; length++) // Change 5 with the length of charset
            test.generate("", 0, length);
    }

}
```

Comment: greate ! but as you see in output. CC comes after BZ and BB comes after AZ. so BA and CA, CB are missed out. and its not in the sequence that is in "stated way". see last output is WZZZ
XXXX
XXXY
XXXZ
XXYY
XXYZ
XXZZ
XYYY
XYYZ
XYZZ
XZZZ
YYYY
YYYZ
YYZZ
YZZZ
ZZZZ

Comment: Mmm. Then I didn't understand the problem. Why not cite the original problem?, maybe the problem is your explanation.

Comment: really like your answer and approach but. let take it an example of a password cracker. now  `BA != AB`. so `BA` is missed out. see the "stated way"

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Generator {

    private char[] charset;

    private int min; //var added for min char length
    private int max; //var added for max char length

    public Generator() {
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAEIOU0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_+=~`[]{}|:;<>,.?/BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".toCharArray();
        min = 2; //char min start
        max = 5; //char max end 
    }

    public void generate(String str, int pos, int length) {
        if (length == 0) {
            System.out.println(str);
        } else {

            //This if statement resets the char position back to the very first character in the character set ('a'), which makes this a complete solution to an all combinations bruteforce! 
            if (pos != 0) {
                pos = 0;
            }

            for (int i = pos; i < charset.length; i++) {
                generate(str + charset[i], i, length - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generator bruteforce = new Generator();

        for (int length = bruteforce.min; length < bruteforce.max; length++) // Change bruteforce.min and bruteforce.max for number of characters to bruteforce. 
            bruteforce.generate("", 0, length); //prepend_string, pos, length 
    }
}
```

> I've modified rendon's example above- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18685721/1  Note: it allow all combinations, and added min and max vars

Answer (score 3):

You can use recusrion and a couple of loops.

```
public static void printCombinations(int length) {
    printCombinations(new char[length], 0, 0);
}

private static void printCombinations(char[] chars, int idx, int mask) {
    if (idx == chars.length) {
        System.out.println(chars);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        int mask2 = 1 << i;
        if ((mask2 & mask) == 0) {
            chars[idx] = (char) ('A' + i);
            printCombinations(chars, idx + 1, mask | mask2);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        printCombinations(i);
}
```

prints

```
A
B
...
ZYWX ... DCBA
```

A combination has no repeating characters so it wouldn't be ZZZZZ...

Comment: the password in a brute force can be zzzzzzzzz. so is a combination of same chars...    like in aa,ab,ac....az.         "aa"

Comment: @MasoodAhmad In that case the solution is much simpler.  You don't need to check for duplicates. I am sure you can modify the code to remove that ;)

Comment: oh ok..but it is no predefined array charset.  as i might want to inlcude `abcdefghi` or include `` %^^&**((@$# ``  special chars. or exclude any.

Comment: Yes, OP does not realise that the key is to understand the answers and apply them as needed... conceptually. Not to use SO as a slave code-writer. +1

Comment: @MasoodAhmad In that case you would need to modify the code to allow more characters.  If you are not a developer, I suggest you hire one. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## A more object orientated solution

### Usage known length

```
final String target = "ABC";
final char[] charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
BruteForce.bruteForce(charset, 5, string -> {
    System.out.println(string);
    return string.equals(target);
});
```

### Usage unknown length

```
final String target = "ABC";
final char[] charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

// Use your looping method of choice
boolean found = false;
int length = 1;
while (!found) {
    found = BruteForce.bruteForce(charset, length, string -> {
        System.out.println(string);
        return string.equals(target);
    });
    length++;
}
```

### Implementation

```
public class BruteForce {

    public static boolean bruteForce(@NonNull final char[] input, final int length, @NonNull final Closure closure) {
        final char[] chars = new char[length];
        final IncrementalCharSequence incrementalCharSequence = new IncrementalCharSequence(input, chars);

        // Use your looping method of choice
        do {
            if (closure.compare(new String(chars))) {
                return true;
            }
        } while (incrementalCharSequence.increment());
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Closure {

    boolean compare(@NonNull final String string);
}
```

```
public class IncrementalCharSequence {

    @NonNull
    private final char[] input;

    @Nullable
    private final IncrementalCharSequence subIncrementalCharSequence;

    @NonNull
    private final char[] chars;

    private final int index;

    private int currentIndex;

    public IncrementalCharSequence(@NonNull final char[] input, @NonNull final char[] chars) {
        this(input, chars, 0);
    }

    private IncrementalCharSequence(@NonNull final char[] input, @NonNull final char[] chars, final int index) {
        this.input = input;
        this.chars = chars;
        this.index = index;
        if (index + 1 < chars.length) {
            this.subIncrementalCharSequence = new IncrementalCharSequence(input, chars, index + 1);
        } else {
            this.subIncrementalCharSequence = null;
        }
        currentIndex = 0;
        chars[index] = input[currentIndex];
    }

    /**
     * Increment the char sequence
     *
     * @return {@code true} if incremented, {@code false} if rolled over to zero index
     */
    public boolean increment() {
        if (subIncrementalCharSequence != null && subIncrementalCharSequence.increment()) {
            return true;
        } else if (currentIndex < input.length) {
            chars[index] = input[currentIndex];
            currentIndex++;
            return true;
        } else {
            currentIndex = 0;
            chars[index] = input[currentIndex];
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo-code

```
initialize globalComb, an empty array of strings (to keep all combination)
initialize prevComb, an array of strings with an empty string (the previous set of combination)
while(the length of first string in prevComb is not of desired length)
    initialize temp,  an empty array of strings (a temporary one)
    for(each string s in prevComb)
        for(each char c in the alphabet)
            insert s + c in temp
            insert s + c in globalComb
        end for
    end for
    lastComb = temp
return globalComb
```

the size of `globalComb` must be sum(k=1, k=desired length)26^k. If the desired length is 26, I doubt if an average laptop can hold an array of such strings. Instead of storing in a global array, you can just print the strings out.

Answer (score -2):

I have come up with this piece of code 
this will run to 8 didgets/letters
eg. if you are using just capital letters A to Z:
A
B
...
...
ZZZZZZZY
ZZZZZZZZ

```
char[] ch = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    char c1 = ch[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) {
        char c2 = ch[j];
        for (int k = 0; k < ch.length; k++) {
            char c3 = ch[k];
            for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
                char c4 = ch[l];
                for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++) {
                    char c5 = ch[m];
                    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
                        char c6 = ch[n];
                        for (int o = 0; o < 10; o++) {
                            char c7 = ch[o];
                            for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
                                char c8 = ch[p];
                                currentString = "" + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 + c8;
                                System.out.println(currentString);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```