# Find specific sublists in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Let's say that we have the following list:

```
sequence = ['2', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '4', '4']
#indices     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

Next, we have the following list:

```
key_list = ['2', '2', '4']
```

Now, I want to extract all the possible sub-lists from `sequence` that preserve the order of `keylist`, i.e. its indices.

Let me explain by example. So, for `sequence`, all the possible sub-lists of indices which preserve the order of `key_list` are:

```
[0, 3, 5]
[0, 3, 7]
[0, 3, 9]
[0, 3, 10]

[0, 6, 7]
[0, 6, 9]
[0, 6, 10]

[0, 8, 9]
[0, 8, 10]

[3, 6, 7]
[3, 6, 9]
[3, 6, 10]

[3, 8, 9]
[3, 8, 10]

[6, 8, 9]
[6, 8, 10]
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I am working with a big dataset and I have to perform this for every line of the file, so I am looking for a very optimal way to do this, by avoiding brute-force approach (making all possible combinations of the sequence)

P.S. I don't know if the title of the question is appropriate, feel free to change it if you have a better one.

Comment: I think the answer to this question can be similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673812/algorithm-for-largest-word-formed-from-perodic-table-elements/23695758#23695758. Basically your `key_list` is chemical symbols and `sequence` is a word from word list. In particular answer by Colonel Panic should be useful.

Comment: My answer below removes items from sequence up-front before expanding combinations, so if the key has a small subset of the tokens in sequence then it might be what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably needs some optimization and maybe a better structure than a list of lists to avoid the stupid copying and inserting that I'm doing right now, but I think this should do the trick in worst complexity `len(sequence)^2` (not sure about the complexity though).

```
sequence = ['2', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '4', '4']
key_list = ['2', '2', '4']

sub_lists = []
final_sub_lists = set()
len_key_list = len(key_list)

for index, value in enumerate(sequence):
    for sub_list in sub_lists:
        len_sub_list = len(sub_list)
        # Test if current value can continue the current sub list
        if len_sub_list < len_key_list and key_list[len_sub_list] == value:
            if len_sub_list == len_key_list - 1:
                # We have found a complete sub list
                final_sub_lists.add(tuple(sub_list + [index]))
            else:
                # We copy the current sub list to be sure not miss any sub lists
                # like for instance (6, 8, 9) and (6, 8, 10).
                sub_lists.insert(0, sub_list[:])
                sub_list.append(index)
    if key_list[0] == value:
        # Start a new sub list
        sub_lists.append([index])

print sorted(final_sub_lists)
```

Explanation:`sub_lists` is a list of list containing the indexes that have matched so far.  When a `sub_list` has matched all values of `key_list`, it's appended to the set `final_sub_lists`.

It's not fully tested, so feel free to correct or point out optimizations!

Comment: If you leave out the sorting in the end, you approach is the fastest so far (for this specific data). On my machine took your non-sorting code took 54us, my approach took 98us and the `200 OK`'s took about 300us...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this. Apply `combinations()` on `enumerate(sequence)`(with `r=len(key_list)`) to get all r-length combinations from the list, and since `enumerate()` returns both index as well as item we can easily get the indices here:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations               
>>> for c in combinations(enumerate(sequence), len(key_list)):
    indices, data = zip(*c)
    if list(data) == key_list:
        print indices
...         
(0, 3, 5)
(0, 3, 7)
(0, 3, 9)
(0, 3, 10)
(0, 6, 7)
(0, 6, 9)
(0, 6, 10)
(0, 8, 9)
(0, 8, 10)
(3, 6, 7)
(3, 6, 9)
(3, 6, 10)
(3, 8, 9)
(3, 8, 10)
(6, 8, 9)
(6, 8, 10)
```

Comment: Holly molly, that is impressive. But I wonder what is the complexity and if it won't grow too fast, it seems quite bruteforce. I think one could also solve it via building a prefix tree, which would probably scale better.

Comment: I am working with big data set that has to do this for every line in the file, so, is there any way around `combinations`? (Forgot to mention that in the question, I will edit it). Anyway, tnx for the answer, +1.

Comment: @luk32 If I am not wrong then complexity is going to be *len(sequence) CHOOSE len(key_list)* * *the time taken to compare the two lists in each loop*.

Comment: @Belphegor Can't think of anything apart from this right now, someone else will surely come up with an optimal answer.

Comment: @200OK I agree, just for clarification, the `choose` is a binomial coefficient, and it can grow very rapidly with length of the lists. I think the prefix tree can do it in polynomial time something like `O(n*m)` maybe with some `log`s. I think your very neat and concise high score answer might scare off potential answerers =). Maybe if I have time after work I'll take my try at it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach.

I look up every index of the first key. Then I use the same function to look up the following keys and join all the indices...

```
def indexLists(sequence, key_list, seq_start=0, key_start=0):
     """
         seq_start - where I start looking up in sequence
         key_start - which key I am looking up: key = key_list[key_start]
     """
     keyIndexes = []

     # I look up all indices of key_list[key_start] that are higher than seq_start
     while True:

         try:
             keyIndexes.append(
                  sequence.index(
                     key_list[key_start],# what I want to look up
                     keyIndexes[-1]+1 if keyIndexes else seq_start # starting after the last entry or seq_start
                  )
              )
         except:
             break # if there is an error, the are no more indices

     # if there are more entries in key_list
     if key_start+1 < len(key_list):
         # I look up the possible indexes of the following key(s) and combine them
         return [(keyIndex,)+nextKeys  for keyIndex in keyIndexes for nextKeys in indexLists(sequence, key_list, keyIndex+1, key_start+1)]
     else:
         # for the last key in key_list i just return all possible keyIndexes as 1-tuples
         return [(keyIndex, ) for keyIndex in keyIndexes]
```

**Example:**

```
sequence = ['2', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '4', '4']
key_list = ['2', '2', '4']

indexLists(sequence, key_list)
Out[37]: 
[(0, 3, 5),
 (0, 3, 7),
 (0, 3, 9),
 (0, 3, 10),
 (0, 6, 7),
 (0, 6, 9),
 (0, 6, 10),
 (0, 8, 9),
 (0, 8, 10),
 (3, 6, 7),
 (3, 6, 9),
 (3, 6, 10),
 (3, 8, 9),
 (3, 8, 10),
 (6, 8, 9),
 (6, 8, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This expands on Sebastiens answer by recognising that you don't need any of the members of sequence that are not in key_list (now a `key_tuple`), as long as you preserve the original indices of what is left:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> sequence = ['2', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '4', '4']
>>> key_tuple = ('2', '2', '4')
>>> keys = set(key_tuple)
>>> seq = [(indx, val) for indx, val in enumerate(sequence) if val in keys]
>>> seq
[(0, '2'), (1, '4'), (3, '2'), (5, '4'), (6, '2'), (7, '4'), (8, '2'), (9, '4'), (10, '4')]
>>> answer = []
>>> for c in combinations(seq, len(key_tuple)):
...     indxs, vals = zip(*c)
...     if vals == key_tuple:
...         answer.append(indxs)
... 
>>> answer
[(0, 3, 5), (0, 3, 7), (0, 3, 9), (0, 3, 10), (0, 6, 7), (0, 6, 9), (0, 6, 10), (0, 8, 9), (0, 8, 10), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 9), (3, 6, 10), (3, 8, 9), (3, 8, 10), (6, 8, 9), (6, 8, 10)]
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, Python 2.x - adjust for Py3K.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Longest Common Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem in a thin disguise.  The only differences from the usual formulation are that you want the positions, rather than the characters themselves, and that you assume that the `key_list` sequence appears in its entirety as a subsequence of `sequence`, while the LCS problem doesn't make this assumption.

The LCS problem, which is closely related to the problem of optimally aligning two sequences (e.g. DNA sequences), can be solved in O(n^2) time using the [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) dynamic programming algorithm, but that only gives you *one* solution; in the worst case, it could take exponentially long to enumerate all of them (consider the case of looking for a list of k 1s in a list of 2k 1s for large k; there are (2k choose k) answers).  That said, it's just as easy to get the positions as the characters from the DP matrix, and it's straightforward to enumerate all solutions instead of a single one: as you backtrack through the DP matrix, whenever you encounter a cell for which two or all three in-edges have (equal) maximum score (instead of just one in-edge being the unique maximum), recurse to process all of them instead of picking an arbitrary one.

Incidentally, if `key_list` doesn't appear as a subsequence anywhere in `sequence` then the LCS algorithm will find the location of all "nearest" matches -- those positions at which the fewest characters are missing.  This may or may not be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This second answer of mine  finds the indices of all the keys in the sequence *once* then uses a recursive iterator (Python 2.x/3.x so I didn't use `yield from`, to find the possible index combinations:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sequence = ['2', '4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '4', '4']
key_list = ['2', '2', '4']
keys = set(key_list)

key_indices = defaultdict(list)
for indx, val in enumerate(sequence):
    if val in keys:
        key_indices[val].append(indx)
print('key_indices =', key_indices)

def expander(keysleft, indices, sofar=None):
    #print('  keysleft, sofar =', keysleft, sofar )
    if sofar is None :
        sofar = []
    if sofar == []:
        indxleft = -1
    else:
        indxleft = sofar[-1]
    if keysleft:
        keyval, keyrest = keysleft[0], keysleft[1:]
        for keyindx in indices[keyval]:
            if keyindx > indxleft:
                if not keyrest:
                    # No more to do so
                    yield tuple(sofar + [keyindx])
                else:
                    for x in expander(keyrest, indices, sofar + [keyindx]):
                        yield x

ans = list(expander(key_list, dict(key_indices)))
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
key_indices = defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'4': [1, 5, 7, 9, 10], '2': [0, 3, 6, 8]})
[(0, 3, 5), (0, 3, 7), (0, 3, 9), (0, 3, 10), (0, 6, 7), (0, 6, 9), (0, 6, 10), (0, 8, 9), (0, 8, 10), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 9), (3, 6, 10), (3, 8, 9), (3, 8, 10), (6, 8, 9), (6, 8, 10)]
```