# How generate all possible combinations adding items from one list to another in python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ["a", "b"]
list2 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
```

How can I add items from `list2` to the `list1` to generate all possible combinations with different length. Items from the `list1` must always appear complete and at the beginning.

Expected output:

```
result = [["a", "b", "item1"], 
          ["a", "b", "item2"], 
          ["a", "b", "item1", "item2"], 
          ["a", "b", "item1", "item2", "item4"], 
          ["a", "b", "item3", "item4", "item2", "item1"], 
          ...]
```

It is also not required to have several lists that have the same items only the order of items is different. Ex:

```
[["a", "b", "item1", "item2"], ["a", "b", "item2", "item1"]]
```

Comment: Can you have repeats from `list2`? It looks like you want to generate the power set (excluding the empty set) of `list2` (treated as a set of values), then append each element of the power set to a copy of `list1`.

Comment: (Actually, append each *permutation* of each element of the powerset.)

Comment: Clearly `list1` is just a distraction since it is easy to tack it onto the front of any combination of elements from `list2` (combinations which are easy to generatre with `itertools`.)

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074991/generate-all-permutations-of-all-lengths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is your friend here.

*Note: I only added the combinations to another list, `powerset`, for exemplary purposes. In many cases, the number of combinations may be *huge*, and if you were to process the combinations somehow, you would probably want to process each combination separately and not save them to a list. Unless that's your end goal.*

```py
import itertools 

list1 = ["a", "b"]
list2 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"] 

powerset = []
for k in range(1, len(list2)+1):
    for combination in itertools.combinations(list2, k):
        powerset.append(list1 + list(combination))
```

Resulting `powerset`:

```
[['a', 'b', 'item1'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item2'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item3'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item1', 'item2'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item1', 'item3'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item1', 'item4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item2', 'item3'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item2', 'item4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item3', 'item4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item1', 'item2', 'item4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item1', 'item3', 'item4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'],
 ['a', 'b', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']]
```

#### Short explanation

From the docs: The `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)` yields all `r` length subsequences of elements from the input `iterable`. The `iterable` can be any iterable, like a `list` or a `tuple`.

In general *iterable* is any python object with the `__iter__` method that returns an *iterator* (an object which implements `__next__`); iterables can be looped over with `for` loops.