# Given a number, generate a list of all possible combination of X and O with length n

Tags: python, recursion

For example, if `function(2)` then it would produce

```
['XX','XO','OX','OO']
```

I am not sure how I would approach this problem

Comment: This is a small component of my assignment that I could not figure out. Unfortunately, my classes did not learn itertools yet so I don't think I'll be able to utilize this.

Answer (score 5):

Unless this is an assignment, use [`product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from itertools, like this:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(it.product('XO', repeat=2))
[('X', 'X'), ('X', 'O'), ('O', 'X'), ('O', 'O')]
```

If you want to know how to do this the "long" way, an implementation for the `product` method is available in the documentation:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Comment: You might want to join the tuples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your own function do something like this:

```
def crossProduct(A, B):
    #returns cross product of elements in A x elements in B
    return [a+b for a in A for b in B]

suits = 'CDHS'
ranks = '123456789JQKA'

cards = cross(suits,ranks)

print cards # prints out all 52 cards
```

Answer (score 0):

If `function(n - 1)` produces a list of all possible combinations of length `n - 1`, you can recursively generate the combinations of length `n` by returning

1) 'X' concatenated with each element in `function(n - 1)`

2) 'O' concatenated with each element in `function(n - 1)`

Like so:

```
def function(n):
    if n < 1:
        return []
    elif n == 1:
        return ['X', 'O']
    else:
        return ['X' + string for string in function(n - 1)] + ['O' + string
            for string in function(n - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `itertools`, I suggest to consider [binary number representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation). If you iterate through all numbers between `0` and `2^n - 1`, their 0-padded binary representations will yield all possible combinations of `0` and `1`:

```
n = 3
for i in xrange(1<<n):
    print bin(i)[2:].zfill(n)
```

Will print:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

(About the string manipulations, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395356/770830))

The remaining part of the task is how to convert `101` to `XOX`, which can be done manually or, maybe, with [`maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans)/[`translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate).

Note, that this works only for binary alphabets, like `XO` or `|-`.