# How can i convert binary string to its numerical equivalent?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get `toBase10(101)` to spit out `5`.  I also need it to work for numbers besides 101, I know that there is a binary converter built into python but I can't figure it out.

Right now I have

```
def toBase10(x):
    int( 'x' , 2 ) == x
    return x
```

I get the error can't convert non-string with explicit base.  Why can't I use x in here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is most probably a duplicate of: [How do you express binary literals in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476/how-do-you-express-binary-literals-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
def toBase10(x):
    return int(x, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted the integer into a string and then into binary with which I could easily convert into an integer:

```
def binaryconvert(x): 
    x = str(x) 
    binarynumber = int(x, base=2)
    convertnumber = int(binarynumber)
return convertnumber

print(binaryconvert(101))
#the answer would be 5
```

There's also another way if your input is already binary:

```
def binaryconvert(x):
    convertnumber = int(x)
    return convertnumber

x = int(input("Input: "),2)
print(binaryconvert(x))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please review topics at StackOverflow.com/help before your next post. Grammar & spelling are important. Refrain from excuses, & clutter such as please/help/thanks. Good answers are always welcome. Most upvotes are accrued over time as future visitors learn something from your post to apply to their own coding issues. It's place to learn & share. If you see a duplicate question, flag it as such. Rem: explanations are always encouraged, & docs links are welcome (but *always embed* necessary info from the link, too.) Looking forward to your insights.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
def toBase10(item):
     return int(str(item),2)
```

then you can pass either string or int

```
    print toBase10(101)
    print toBase10('101')
```

i think the int cast error is because you are passing in a number not a string, although this looks odd --> "int( x , 2 ) == x" too

Comment: i got it working a little bit ago with some tweaking, thanks for helping