# Syntax Error list/dict

Tags: list, syntax, python-3.x

Python 3:
someList = [0000, 1000, 0100]#, 1100, 0010, 1010, 0110, 1110, 0001, 1001, 0101, 1101, 0011, 1011, 0111, 1111]

have a list which gives me a syntax error if I put more than 2 items in the list

someList = [0000, 1000]  works but if I add anymore it keeps giving me an error

Comment: I don't have Python 3 to test, and it works in Python 2.7.1 without any error, but... it is a mixed octal/decimal list, not binary in any way (`0100` is octal and equal to 64, `1000` is decimal and equal to 1000).

Answer (score 1):

Using the same list, I get a syntax error in Python 3 on your number "0100", not because it is the third item, but rather, due to the value itself.  I also get a syntax error just doing

```
someList = []
someList.append(0100)
```

So really it seems to be the value causing the problem.  I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but if you just want binary literals in a list, you can use something like this:

```
someList = [0b0000, 0b1000, 0b0100, 0b1100, 0b0010, 0b1010, 0b0110, 0b1110, 0b0001, 0b1001, 0b0101, 0b1101, 0b0011, 0b1011, 0b0111, 0b1111]
```

..where the "0b" prefix (that's zero b) represents a binary number.

Interesting link on the different python versions and their handling of base literal values here:
[How do you express binary literals in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476/how-do-you-express-binary-literals-in-python)