# Confused about how to perform bitwise operations on 16bit binary number in python shell

Tags: python, shell, bit, bitwise-operators

I'm learning about bitwise operators in python and so I tried to do some experimentation in the shell. I tried doing bit manipulation with 8bit numbers and that seems to work normally, but if I try to use 16bit numbers this happens:

```
>>> b = 0010000000000000
>>> b
549755813888
```

If I try a larger number the output seems normal at first:

```
a = 1011110110011001
>>> a
1011110110011001

>>> b = 1100001110000101
>>> b
1100001110000101
```

But when I apply a bitwise operator, for instance `OR |,`then I get a decimal output again.

```
>>> a | b
1125874135965693
```

I find this very confusing. Isn't the result of binary operators supposed to be binaries? If so where does the conversion happen? And finally, why does this only happen when I try it with 16-bit binaries?

EDIT: I get the following when trying 8bits:

```
>>> c = 00000001
>>> d = 10000000
>>> c | d
10000001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't told Python that you're entering binary numbers; like C, Python will interpret 0010000000000000 as octal (8**13), and 1011110110011001 as decimal. Use the 0b prefix and bin function instead:

```
>>> a = 0b1011110110011001
>>> b = 0b1100001110000101
>>> bin(a|b)
'0b1111111110011101'
```

Your 8-bit (Python doesn't know that either, int is typically 32 or 64 bits but recent versions will seamlessly transition to long which can go to any width) values were interpreted the exact same way. It's just that 1 is 1 no matter how many zeroes are put in front, in any base, and the other number was even. Try `100 | 1000` (which produces 1004) for a low example where this fails (actual values are 0b1111101000 and 0b1100100).

Comment: This makes sense, but does the interpreter automatically recognize 8-bits as binaries without the '0b' prefix then?

Comment: You might want to post an example of 8-bit values that you think are working.

Answer (score 1):

Although you're only using `1`s and `0`s, this doesn't make the numbers you're typing in binary numbers: they're decimal (or octal if you start with `0`).

If you want to use binary numbers, prefix them with `0b` (assuming Python 2.6 at least). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1476/372643).

You may also find [`bin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) useful if you want to print out the results.

---

> EDIT: I get the following when trying 8bits:
>
> ```
> >>> c = 00000001
> >>> d = 10000000
> >>> c | d
> 10000001
> ```

You're still confused about the `0b` notation. `10000000` isn't an 8-bit number, it's a decimal number, and you need at least 24 bits to represent it (`bin(10000000)` is `0b100110001001011010000000`).

The reason `10000000 | 00000001` appears to "work" as if it was a binary representation is that `00000001` (which is an octal representation) also happens to be 1 in decimal. This really is `0b100110001001011010000000 | 0b000000000000000000000001`.

For example, `00000010` is `8` in decimal, so `10000000 | 00000010` would be `10000008`. If your number starts with `0`, it's an octal representation; if it starts with `0x`, it's hexadecimal; if it starts with `0b`, it's binary; otherwise, it's decimal.

There is a bit of luck with your particular use case (`10000000 | 1`). Try `10000000 | 1000`, and your assumptions no longer work: that's `10000360`.

The operations you're using are bitwise, but the `1`s in the numbers you are providing do not represent individual bits.

What you'd probably want to see is:

```
>>> bin(0b10000000 | 0b00001000)
'0b10001000'
```

Here the number you're providing are in binary format (`0b...`), the operation is bitwise (the operation was also bitwise for the other notations, it's just that the activated bits were not those you thought they were) and then you turn it back into a binary representation with `bin(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

To write binary literals in Python you need to prefix the literal with `0b`. As in `a = 0b1011110110011001`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476/how-do-you-express-binary-literals-in-python) for more detail.