# Odd behavior of Python operator.xor

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, xor

I am working on an encryption puzzle and am needing to take the exclusive or of two binary numbers (I'm using the `operator` package in Python).  If I run `operator.xor(1001111, 1100001)` for instance I get the very weird output `2068086`.  Why doesn't it return `0101110` or at least `101110`?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? 1001111 isn't binary.

Comment: I thought it would just be understood that the arguments were supposed to be binary numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Python doesn't see that as binary numbers. Instead use:

```
operator.xor(0b1001111, 0b1100001)
```

Answer (score 7):

The calculated answer is using the decimal values you provided, not their binary appearance. What you are really asking is...

```
1001111 ^ 1100001
```

When you mean is `79 ^ 97`. Instead try using the binary literals as so...

```
0b1001111 ^ 0b1100001
```

See [How do you express binary literals in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476/how-do-you-express-binary-literals-in-python) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Because `1001111` and `1100001` are not binary numbers. `1001111` is One million, one thousand, one hundred and eleven, while `1100001` is One million, one hundred thousands and one. Python doesn't recognize these as binary numbers. Binary numbers have to be prefixed with `0b` to be recognized as binary numbers in Python/Python 3. So the correct way is this:

```
operator.xor(0b1001111, 0b1100001)
```

But hey! We get `46` as output. We should fix that. Thankfully, there IS a built-in in Python/Python 3. It's the function `bin(n)`. That function prints a number a binary, prefixed with `0b`. So our final code would be:

```
bin(operator.xor(0b1001111, 0b1100001))
```

If we want to hide the `0b` (mostly in cases where that number is printed to the screen), we should use `[2:]` like this:

```
bin(operator.xor(0b1001111, 0b1100001))[2:]
```

**A shorter way (warning looks like a tutorial for something you *should* already know)**
Well, `operator.xor()` is too big for an operator :)
If that is the case (99.9%), instead you should use `a^b`. I think you already know this but why to import a whole module just for the xor operator? If you like to type the word `xor` instead, import the `operator` module like this: `from operator import a, b...`. Then use like this: `bin(xor(a,b))`. I hope you already know that stuff but I want to make sure you enjoy coding even more :)