# How to declare a list of 32 bit binary numbers and shift in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, bit-shift, 32-bit

I am trying to declare a list of 32-bit binary numbers (1's and 0's) in Python, pick out a number in the list, and shift.

This is how I have my list declared, but I do not feel like this is correct.

```
myList = [11111011001101011001101011001100, 11111111000011001101001100111111,
     11000000111100001111000011110000, 11111111000000001111011100001111]
```

Now I want to select a number from my list and shift it to the left by 4

Example:

```
num = myList[0]
example = num << 4
print("original", num)
print("shifted", example)
```

The output looks like this:

```
original 11111011001101011001101011001100
shifted 177776176017616176017616176017600
```

How can I fix my declaration and shifting issues? Thanks

Comment: Use **0b**11100011... to declare binary numbers. Print with `bin(number)`.

Comment: Incidentally, there is no such thing as a "binary number" type in Python. Or any other base, for that matter. `0b11111111` and `0xFF` and `255` are all exactly identical ordinary integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you express binary literals in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476/how-do-you-express-binary-literals-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
11111011001101011001101011001100
```

is interpreted as **a decimal number**. So the ones and the zeros represent powers of 10. You can **use the `0b` prefix** to specify you are writing binary numbers, so:

```
myList = [0b11111011001101011001101011001100, 0b11111111000011001101001100111111,
          0b11000000111100001111000011110000, 0b11111111000000001111011100001111]
num = myList[0]
example = num << 4
print("original", bin(num))
print("shifted", bin(example))
```

You can use `bin(..)` to generate a string for a number that shows the binary notation. This will print:

```
>>> print("original", bin(num))
original 0b11111011001101011001101011001100
>>> print("shifted", bin(example))
shifted 0b111110110011010110011010110011000000
```

Note that in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), `int`s have **arbitrary length**. So if you want to obtain a 32-bit number, **you will have to mask with `0xffffffff`** (that is 32 set bits, so `0b11111111111111111111111111111111`):

```
myList = [0b11111011001101011001101011001100, 0b11111111000011001101001100111111,
          0b11000000111100001111000011110000, 0b11111111000000001111011100001111]
num = myList[0]
example = (num << 4)&0xffffffff
print("original", bin(num))
print("shifted", bin(example))
```

Comment: leave some reputation for others to gain, you are always so fast:)

Comment: @GijsDenHollander: noted. Next time I will give you five minutes :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you!